# Lebesgue measure of a lower-bounded set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A \subset (0, 1)$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and let $k > 0$. Suppose that if $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$, then $\mu_L(A \cap (a, b)) \geq k\mu_{L}((a, b))$. Prove that $\mu_L(A) = 1.$

I thought to prove that $\mu_L(A^c)=0$ by covering it by a union of intervals that could be as small as I wanted, but I couldn't do it. I don't think it is a hard one... it just needs some trick I can't think of right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$.  If $\mu_L((0,1)\setminus A)=a$, then there is an open set $U$ with $((0,1)\setminus A)\subseteq U\subseteq (0,1)$ such that $\mu_L(U)<a+\varepsilon$.  Because $U$ is a countable disjoint union of open intervals, your hypothesis implies that $\mu_L(U\cap A)\geq k\mu_L(U)\geq ka$.  But then $a+\varepsilon>\mu_L(U)=\mu_L(U\setminus A)+\mu_L(U\cap A)=\mu_L((0,1)\setminus A)+\mu_L(U\cap A)\geq a+ka$.  This implies that $a<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{k}$.  Because $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this implies that $a=0$.

Comment: How do we know that such a $U$ exists? From the definition of the measure, I can see that we can find a $U$ with $\mu_L(U)<a+\varepsilon$ but how can we be sure that $U$ will be a subset of $(0,1)$? And this is for $\varepsilon < 1-\alpha$, right?

Comment: @JohnDoe: If it is not already a subset of $(0,1)$, then you can intersect with $(0,1)$. There is no upper bound needed for $\varepsilon$, but you can add a positive upper bound without harm.  I do not understand the motivation for doing so.

Comment: You are right about the upper bound, I was confused, it is not needed. Thanks for your answer, it is clear to me now!